# iPhone old backup

Tags: backup, iphone

There are two backups shown in the `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` in my laptop.
I want to restore the older backup from it using iTunes.

How can I select one of the backups and ask iTunes to restore the selected backup to iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right click on the phone in iTunes (it used to be on the sidebar, now I think the icon is on top) and select restore from backup.
When you do that, a dialog box pops up with a drop down asking you to select which backup you want to use.

Comment: Yes it shows select the option then in dropping bar list it shows my iphone name and a button restore. if i select this will it give me options of backups stored in this computer?

Comment: No, those ARE the available options to restore from. If it's only showing you one, then that's the only one available to use.